Error updating initramfs-tools and raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware on Raspberry Pi
I'm setting up FlightRadar24 and I'm trying to update the packages.  I keep getting the same error.
Thanks in advance, and yes, im a rookie.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142+deb12u1) ...

update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

Setting up linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (1:6.6.51-1+rpt3) ...

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712

stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?

run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1

run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Setting up linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (1:6.6.51-1+rpt3) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1

run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-rpi-2712:
 linux-image-rpi-2712 depends on linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-rpi-2712 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up raspi-firmware (1:1.20240924-1) ...
stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package raspi-firmware (--configure):
 installed raspi-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-rpi-v8:
 linux-image-rpi-v8 depends on linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-rpi-v8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712:
 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 depends on linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3) | linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712-unsigned (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 is not configured yet.
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712-unsigned is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8:
 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 depends on linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3) | linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8-unsigned (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 is not configured yet.
  Package linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8-unsigned is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-rpi-2712:
 linux-headers-rpi-2712 depends on linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-rpi-2712 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-rpi-v8:
 linux-headers-rpi-v8 depends on linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 (= 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-rpi-v8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142+deb12u1) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712
 linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
 linux-image-rpi-2712
 raspi-firmware
 linux-image-rpi-v8
 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712
 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
 linux-headers-rpi-2712
 linux-headers-rpi-v8
 initramfs-tools

Also when i do a upgrade i get....
> **bookworm:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done
> Calculating upgrade... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
> and 0 not upgraded. 10 not fully installed or removed. After this
> operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.**

And...
pi@pi24-bookworm:~ $ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142+rpt1+deb12u1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up raspi-firmware (1:1.20240924-2) ...
stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package raspi-firmware (--configure):
 installed raspi-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142+rpt1+deb12u1) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
pi@pi24-bookworm:~ $ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142+rpt1+deb12u1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up raspi-firmware (1:1.20240924-2) ...
stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package raspi-firmware (--configure):
 installed raspi-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142+rpt1+deb12u1) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8.dpkg-bak' => '/boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
stat: cannot read file system information for '/boot/firmware': No such file or directory
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 raspi-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


What happens if you attempt the update after issuing sudo mount /boot?

i figured it out.
I need to
sudo mkdir /boot/firmware
mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M firmware /boot/firmware
Thank you though

FIXED
Test Temp File:
sudo mkdir /boot/firmware 

mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M firmware /boot/firmware

Made Permenant:
cp -r /boot/firmware /tmp/

umount /boot/firmware

rm -r /boot/firmware

cp -r /tmp/firmware /boot/firmware

Not sure why this happened.
Hopefully this helps someone else

You need to keep that directory /boot/firmware is updated each time a new kernel is added, or a new firmware version is added.

See here for why I recommend keeping the directory.

Always good to see people follow up when they fix their own problems, well done!

Here's a somewhat shorter version that doesn't require making a second copy: umount -lf /boot/firmware ; cd /boot/firmware && mount /boot/firmware && cp -a /boot/firmware/. . && umount /boot/firmware (This relies on a process's current directory being an inode rather than a path.)
